# Exception : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printwriter

I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>   at JavaProject.main(JavaProject.java:70)

Here is the code:

```java
try
{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Gamer Report Data.txt");
    writer.println("Player: " + gamerName);
    writer.println();
    writer.println("-------------------------------");
    String[] report = gamerReport.split(gamerReport, ':');
    writer.println("Game:" + ", score=" + report[1] + ", minutes played=" + report[2] + report[3]);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("File does not exist!");
}
```

I believed it to be something related to my `for` loop, but I have had no luck changing it around.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class JavaProject {

    private static char[] input;

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int b = 1; b < 100; b++) { 
            // this is making the code loop 100 times

            int hrs, mins;
            int[] gameCount;
            int[] minutesPlayed = new int[100];
            String gamerName, gamerReport;

            // Main data storage arrays
            String[] gameNames = new String[100];
            int[] highScores = new int[100];

            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            // formatting for output and input
            System.out.println("////// Game Score Report Generator \\\\\\\\\\\\");
            System.out.println("     ");

            // user enters name and then moves to next line
            System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
            gamerName = Scan.nextLine();

            // user is given an example of input format 
            System.out.println("Input Gamer Information " + "Using Format --> Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
            System.out.println("    ");

            System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
            gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

            String[] splitUpReport; // an array of string
            splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":"); // split the text up on the colon

            int i = 0;

            // copy data from split text into main data storage arrays 
            gameNames[i] = splitUpReport[0];
            highScores[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim());
            minutesPlayed[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());

            // output to file 

            try
            {
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Gamer Report Data.txt");
                writer.println("Player: " + gamerName);
                writer.println();
                writer.println("-------------------------------");
                String[] report = gamerReport.split(gamerReport, ':');
                writer.println("Game:" + ", score=" + report[1] + ", minutes played=" + report[2] + report[3]);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("File does not exist!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static char[] getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public static void setInput(char[] input) {
        JavaProject.input = input;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is most likely coming from the `report[]` array.  Unfortunately, you omitted the code where the string `gamerReport` is defined/assigned, so we can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: edited it to include the full code

Comment: What value are you entering in the console for `gamerReport` ?  If it doesn't have at least two colons (the punctuation kind, not the human organ), then you will get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which you are seeing.

Comment: I'm entering the data as expected https://i.gyazo.com/b97e1c332ef4a31a669022cf5c54fab8.png 
no human colons present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1)

```
String[] report = gamerReport.split(gamerReport, ':');
```

should be

```
String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
```

as you did with `splitUpReport` (not sure why you're splitting again actually).

2) Arrays are zero-indexed, so the print statement should look like this:

```
writer.println("Game:" + ", score=" +report[0] +", minutes played="+ report[1] + report[2]);
```

Comment: Good catch on the array indices.

Comment: @BrandonParkinson you need to pass a string to the `split()` method: `":"`, not `':'`.

Comment: Actually, there is an overloaded version of `String.split()` which takes a regex as the first parameter, and an `int` limit as the second parameter.  By coincidence, his code compiles and runs though not as intended.

Comment: So you are saying my code should not technically run?

Comment: @BrandonParkinson, it runs because you're passing `gamerReport` as a regex string, and a `char` (`':'`) as an `int`. Either a freak accident or unlucky guesswork.

Comment: Ah I see. Also could I ask do you know how to change the formatting for the output to .txt? At the moment when output the format is https://i.gyazo.com/e4bde4e5f78988dd3d349b436128210f.png 
when i would much prefer it to output like - https://i.gyazo.com/def6e157e24dc0ed0fe68e1509152405.png

Comment: @BrandonParkinson Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The first image (https://i.gyazo.com/e4bde4e5f78988dd3d349b436128210f.png) is what it looks like when i run the code and open the output file and the second image (https://i.gyazo.com/def6e157e24dc0ed0fe68e1509152405.png) is what i want it to look like. How can i make it do this

Comment: @BrandonParkinson, there are a number of difference between the two images. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have fixed it but thank-you. I just wanted to do proper formatting like Game: Minecraft, Score: 44 
etc, rather than being messy. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is being caused by this code in the `try` block:

```
String[] report = gamerReport.split(gamerReport, ':');
```

You are actually trying to split the `gamerReport` string using itself as a regex, with a `limit` of `58`, which is the numerical value of the colon.

The result of this split is 2 empty `String` elements, which correspond to the match happening *before* and *after* the regex, which is the string itself.

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is happening when you try to access the third element from this array:

To fix your problem, just define the `report` array as follows:

```
String[] report = gamerReport.split(':');
```

As @shmosel pointed out, you might also want to change your array indices here as well:

```
writer.println("Game:" + ", score=" + report[0] +", minutes played="+ report[1] + report[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response very helpful